# See only 1 view from several list views

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have two issues:
1) I have several views created on a list but would like to see only 1 when i access that view by a link:
Now i see :
"All Items" "View1" "View2" "View3"
but when i access View3 using the link i would like to see:
"View3" and no direct access to the other views.
Today i see all the views.

2) I can select any of the items from the view and then use Edit Item : i would like to disable this possibility and garantee that this is a datasheet view only editable in an excel mode. I cannot select one item.

Do you know if this is possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

Method 1:

Create multiple pages and add list view web part for specific list view in each page. You can specify the list view for the list view web part by editing this web part > Selected View.

Then use the following script to hide the list view dropdown.

```
<style>
#RibbonContainer #Ribbon\.List\.CustomViews #Ribbon\.List\.CustomViews-LargeMedium-2-1,
#RibbonContainer #Ribbon\.List\.CustomViews #Ribbon\.List\.CustomViews-LargeMedium-2-0
{
display : none;
}
</style>
```

Method 2:

You can set [target audience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293) to show particular list view web part for different user group.

By using Target Audiences, we can display content such as entire Web Part to specific groups of people. If the account you are using to visit this web part is not a member of Target Audiences, even if you are an admin, you cannot view the content in this web part. But when editing the page, the admin can view the content in the web part.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the view page, such as “View1.aspx”.
2. Edit this page and edit the list view web part.
3. Advanced > Target Audience.

**Issue 2**

An idea to achieve that, use script to hide Edit options on the page.
Use F12 get elements of Edit options and then use CSS or JavaScript to hide them.

Comment: If you think it is helpful, you can "accept" this answer. Thanks